# Matlab / Parse binary file read into memory

Tags: matlab, binaryfiles

I'm working with a heterogeneous binary file written by a 3rd party software package.  I've found that one bottleneck in my **Matlab** code is reading this file.  I read it line-by-line because the next item I need to read depends upon the information I just read in the file.

Several postings encourage reading the whole file into memory.  Sounds great.  However, nobody provides examples of what to do with the byte stream that is in memory.  It is a lot of work to go byte-by-byte and assign data to *int32*, *char*, *double*.  Is there an easier way to read the data in and/or parse it?

```
fp = fopen('test.bin', 'wb');
fwrite(fp, 1, 'double');
fwrite(fp, 1, 'int32');
fclose(fp);
```

So, how would I read this in this binary data and parse it?

---

The following is the description of the file format from the 3rd party software manual:

> The first record in the file is a single 32-bit integer indicating the
> version and format number of the ZRD file. The second record in the
> file is a single 32-bit integer indicating the maximum possible number
> of segments in the remaining records. The actual number of segments
> will always be less than or equal to this number.
>
> The remainder of the file consists of a 32-bit integer indicating the
> number of segments that follows, then that many segments, then another
> 32-bit integer indicating the number of segments in the next record,
> and so on until the end of the file. A single ray segment is described
> by a “C” structure with the following format:

```
typedef struct
{
unsigned int status;
int level;
int hit_object;
int hit_face;
int unused;
int in_object;
int parent;
int storage;
int xybin, lmbin;
double index, starting_phase;
double x, y, z;
double l, m, n;
double nx, ny, nz;
double path_to, intensity;
double phase_of, phase_at;
double exr, exi, eyr, eyi, ezr, ezi;
} RAYPATH;
```

Comment: What format does the data have? That is, how should the byte stream be interpreted in your case? [`typecast`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) may be useful

Comment: I added the format to the post.  It is not a simple format that can be addressed merely by associating a block of data with an array or similar.

Comment: This is something really easy to do efficiently in C or C++, not so much in MATLAB. I would write a MEX-file to load the data.

Comment: I agree... it is easier in C / C++.  I may try a MEX file.  The data structure is a bit complex.  I am hoping it is not hard to map the data from the MEX file to a structure and/or object in Matlab.  This ( https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatestructarray.html ) seems to do the trick.